# Removing unused Rows from jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rows, defaulttablemodel

How do I remove unused rows from a `JTable`?

I first create a table of a fixed size in a `JPanel` and then fill elements as needed.

Now I don't want unused rows to be displayed in my table. Please help.

Comment: What is unused mean here and what have you tried?

Comment: I presently get a table with lots of empty rows in bottom, only top 5-6 rows being used, with rest blank. I want to hide them or remove them somehow.

Comment: What model are u using ?

Comment: its DefaultTableModel, as provided impilcitly by netbeans

Comment: _a table of a fixed size_ ??? Why do you do that if you know that you won't use all rows? Rather create an empty TableModel with the default columns and then add your rows dynamically, as you need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I presently get a table with lots of empty rows in bottom, only top 5-6 rows being used, with rest blank. I want to hide them or remove them somehow

Work the other way around. Start with an empty DefaultTableModel. DefaultTableModel supports an `addRow()` method. So, as you get data to add to the model use:

model.addRow(...);

Don't let the GUI editor determine how you code your GUI. Adding cleanup code to remove rows is a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

DefaultTableModel has a method [removeRow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#removeRow%28int%29) which removes a row from the table. Pass the row index which you want to remove from the table.

> Now I don't want unused rows to be displayed in my table.

This I am not sure please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to show us what is the flag that says these rows are not used.