# load text file of 100 records 10 by 10 jtable java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, limit

!I have file which has 100 records, I used Jtable to show records 15 by 15  and go on. I am new to JFC concepts, I created a jtable with 15 rows, in my jtable first 15 rows displaying flawless. From 16th row onwards,it does not show any records. My question is how to display next 15 records in the same jtable? and go on till the end of the text file.

Finally, i need to Remove the empty rows.`

```
       for (int initial = 0; initial < rowLength; initial++) 
        {

        for (int j = 0; j < aIndex; j++) 
        {
            TableData[initial][j] = cName[k];
        System.out.println(TableData[initial][j]);              
                      k++;
        }

        }`   And I not used any scrollpanes specifically.
```

Comment: Firstly, that seems like a strange requirement, why not just display the entire contents of the file.  Second of you should supply a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so can help guide with some ideas

Comment: Your program has a TableModel? The best why is if you program one by yourself. If you have one use a Method that set the data in the Table and fire the table. Very Easy :)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175139/jtable-row-limitation) question can help you.

Comment: That depends on how you fill your TableModel. Easiest way is to read all rows from file. You are probably reading only first 15 rows. So if you want help please provide some code on how do you read data and set them to table

Comment: @MadProgrammer loading data into JTable by using, creating some Batch logics is quite periodically asked here, this is very nice for enduser, phaaaa animations, SwingWorker & publish()

Comment: @mKorbel I can understand batch loading the file, but it sounds more like the way to do interactive page loading...

Comment: @MadProgrammer `I have Jtable in that I need to show records 15 by 15 and go on.` if you meaning this, then yes, you are right

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6175860/418556) for a working example.

Comment: @VimalBera in this case, i have 25 records, each page i showing 10 records at last 5 records shown, and remaining 5 rows will be empty. i don't want to show empty rows or blank rows to my user, how to proceed?

Comment: @arvind for that, refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478688/removing-unused-rows-from-jtable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own TableModel for your JTable. Use a AbstractTableModel it should be easy and configurable enough for you program!

In the Model you have to use a constructor, this should look like this:

```
public Model(ArrayList<Object[]> data, String[] header) {
    this.data = data;
    this.header = header;
}
```

At the beginning use two private fields, to save and work with your data in your TableModel:

```
private ArrayList<Object[]> data;
private String[] header
```

If you have already a TableModel use a Method that sets the data in your Table, like:

```
public void setTableData(ArrayList<Object[]> data) {
    this.data = data;
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

**Importent** is that you fire the table and notify listeners with fireTableDataChanged() or somthing similar(only specifed cells for example)!

At the line where you want to change the Data use:

```
Model model = (Model) table.getModel();
model.setTableData(data);
```